How can i update my helm chart when there is new commit?
im new to helm and gitlab..
Im trying to create a simple pipeline, once i commit my code -> my helm chart in the repo updates (and takes the new image tag, which is the commit)
Currently my gitlab repo looks like this:
Project
  src/ (source code)
  chart/ (my helm chart)

once i commit my source code, a new build is created with the tag being the commit SHA, but how can i also update my helm chart (possibly through the gitlab ci) to take the latest tag?
my Values file looks like this
replicas: 1
registry: XX
image: YY
image_tag: ZZ (this one should be changes every new build)
port: 8000

also, im not sure if its best practice to keep the chart and the source code on the same repo (but im just learning for now)
i thought i might need to do it throught the gitlab ci, but i think this will just create "spam" commits (every new build, i pull the repo, update the file and commit. but i think this is kinda spammy and maybe there is a better way)

Can your CI system helm upgrade --set-string image_tag=...?  That would avoid needing to actually change anything at deploy time.

not really, the gitlab ci is not connected to my kubernetes cluster. i’m gonna watch it using argoCD

This is not recommended. The source code and helm charts should be in their separate repos. The helm chart is not only about image but rather controls a lot of other deployment configuration. So keep them separate(CI & CD) and developer should update helm values file as a separate action to control and trigger CD pipeline.

I've seen both kinds of setups, where the chart is both in the same repo as the source code and where it's separate; it seems to largely depend on whether developers or a separate DevOps team maintains the chart (not necessarily the deploy-time settings but the chart itself).  Either way is fine, but you do need some coordination for per-environment and per-deployment settings.

i see, and considering that i have 2 repos now. one for src and one for helm. every commit to the src (code) i run gitlab ci with the commit sha and send it to the helm gitlab ci, then update it? is that the correct flow?

You need to have 2 repository on Gitlab:

Helm Chart: When you have your Chart is ready, you need to create a tag and create a release on the tag
Source Code: On your gitlab-ci, in your job of deployment you need to add 1. to helm repository:

_
# Add your package repository
helm repo add --username gitlab-ci-token --password $CI_JOB_TOKEN target_repo "your.url.of.gitlab.com/$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/projectNumber/packages/path/to/your/package
helm repo update

# Use helm with your package
helm upgrade --install "nameOfYourChart" \
  "target_repo/nameOfYourChart" \
  --version "numberOfTag" \
  --values "path/to/custom/values.yaml/in/repository/of/source/code" \
  --set key.to.image.digest=$DIGEST_IMAGE

key.to.image.digest represent the digest will be replace in your values.yaml like:
key:
  to:
    image:
      imageName: your.url.of.gitlab.com/project/source/code/image
      digest: ""

